# How to make this PHP if statement more simple and shorter?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have feeling that the following code can be shortened but have no idea how to rewrite it :)

```
$post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';

if( $post_type == 'faq' && !isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] ) )
  $_REQUEST['mode'] = 'excerpt';

// if I just go with else... it doesn't work
elseif( $post_type !== 'faq' && !isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] ) )
  $_REQUEST['mode'] = 'list';
```

**Update**

As you can see, `!isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] )` is used twice.
`$post_type == 'faq'` is also used twice, but in the elseif I'm checking negative.

Seriously there is no way to rewrite it to one `if` without `else`...?

Comment: Maybe something like: `if(!isset($_REQUEST['mode'])){ if($post_type === 'faq'){} else{} }`?

Comment: You should learn about [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). What your doing is this algebra, and knowing the rules would help you simplify the statements.

Comment: You want to make it more shorter so the other developers gets into troubles while reading your code

Comment: This is for me not for others... @RocketHazmat you're using a lot of { and }

Comment: @RafcioKowalsky: I'd suggest you use the `{}` wherever possible.  What if you want to add a 2nd line to the `if` block?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I like it without {}, and I won't add more lines to it ;)

Comment: @RafcioKowalsky Most of the world would disagree with you on that point.

Comment: @Brad why do you think so?

Comment: @RafcioKowalsky For the same reason RocketHazmat just said, you will likely end up adding more lines at some point anyway.  For me, it's easier to skim code when the appropriate brackets are in place.  Most code I've seen uses them unconditionally for conditionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a ternary operator for testing 'faq' ?

```
$post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';
if (!isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] )) {
    $_REQUEST['mode'] = ($post_type == 'faq') ? 'excerpt' : 'list';
}
```

Comment: I choose your answer because I understand it most and it's shorter than mine. And I can also omit the {}.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use more intermediate variables, to improve readability of the if statements.

```
$post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';
$notRequestMode=!isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] );

if( $post_type == 'faq' &&  $notRequestMode)
  $_REQUEST['mode'] = 'excerpt';

// if I just go with else... it doesn't work
elseif( $post_type !== 'faq' && $notRequestMode)
  $_REQUEST['mode'] = 'list';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance you have a lot of `$post_type`, so I would first set that within a `switch`:

```
switch($post_type) {
case 'faq':
  // code here
  break;

case 'somethingElse':
  // code here
  break;

// etc.
```

From there, you could even nest another switch in for `$_REQUEST['mode']` if appropriate, or just include your `if` statements.

As a note on formatting, if I have a lot of conditions, I will put those conditions on multiple lines:

```
if (
  $post_type == 'faq' && 
  !isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] ) && 
  // more conditions here
) {
```

Comment: I just wanted to simplify more and more my code. I don't need to check for more $post_type's, only for 'faq'. Sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: @RafcioKowalsky In that case, just have a single outer `if` statement for your `$post_type === 'faq'`, and inner `if` statements for the rest of the conditions.

Comment: @RafcioKowalsky Well you could, but it would be awfully confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want short, here's short based on your example code.

```
if(!isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] )){
$_REQUEST['mode'] = 'list';
if($_GET['post_type']=="faq")
$_REQUEST['mode'] = 'excerpt';
}
```

Comment: need to check if post_type is set though

Answer (score 0):

Your actual code can be resolved to:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['mode'])) {
  if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
    $_REQUEST['mode'] = ($_GET['post_type'] == 'faq') ? 'excerpt' : 'list';
  }
}
```

But is it really better? I mean, you're surely going back to your code some time in the future...

Comment: I can leave a comment above my code, so after a few months I can still understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';
$_REQUEST['mode'] = !isset($_REQUEST['mode'])?(($post_type==='faq')?'excerpt':'list'):'';
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.3+ you can use the shortened ternary:

```
$post_type = $_GET['post_type'] ?: '';
if (!isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] )) {
  $_REQUEST['mode'] = $post_type == 'faq' ? 'excerpt' : 'list';
}
```

But the shortest is probably:

```
if (!isset( $_REQUEST['mode'] )) {
  $_REQUEST['mode'] = isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'faq' ? 'excerpt' : 'list';
}
```

Or on a single line with the shortened ternary:

```
$_REQUEST['mode'] = $_REQUEST['mode'] ?: (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'faq' ? 'excerpt' : 'list');
```